# How can I override a parameter in CC_SYNTHESIZE in c++?

Tags: c++, overriding, cocos2d-x-3.0

as I told, I don't understand how can I override a CC_SYNTHESIZE. I want to remove a warning on this line.

```
CC_SYNTHESIZE(**int** , idObject, IdObject);

WARNING:
'getIdObject' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override'
'setIdObject' overrides a member function but is not marked 'override'
```

How can I resolve this? thank you for reading and sorry if is a dumb question

Comment: either don't use the macro or modify it to add the override keyword

Comment: how can I modify it to add override keyword?

Comment: you'd have to update the cocos source code

Comment: ok... I guess I'll remove the macro then! thank you for the quick answer!